# Materialize Chips Limit option is not working

Tags: materialize

I am using materialize chips autocomplete, but i think the limit option is not working.
With limit option I guess that it refers to the maximum number of chips that can be selected.
For example, I put limit 3, but it allows me to add all the available.
How can I limit to select up to 3 options?

html code

```
<div class="chips-autocomplete"></div>
```

chips initialization

```
<script src="js/materialize.js"></script>    
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'Apple': null,
                'Microsoft': null,
                'Android': null,
                'Facebook': null,
                'Twitter': null,
                'Amazon': null,
                'Google': null
            },
            limit: 3,
            minLength: 1
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize chips has two limit options.  Limit within autocompleteOptions and limit within chips options:

- autocomplete options => this limits the number of suggestions you will see when trying to add a new chip.  Ref here in the documentation: https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html
- chips options => this sets the maximum number of chips allowed, which is what you want. Ref here in the documentation: https://materializecss.com/chips.html

So to get the limit on number of chips you can add, move limit outside autoCompleteOptions like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
        data: {
            'Apple': null,
            'Microsoft': null,
            'Android': null,
            'Facebook': null,
            'Twitter': null,
            'Amazon': null,
            'Google': null
        }
    },
    limit: 3,
    minLength: 1
    }
});
</script>
```